# What is the difference between Project Name and artifact ID?

Tags: eclipse, maven

Using eclipse, when I want to create a new maven project I am required to supply both artifact Id and a project name.

I find it hard to understand what is the difference between them.
 Is it correct that one artifact Id can be used for multiple projects?

Thank you.

Comment: That's just an Eclipse matter. The artifactId is for Maven. Maven needs it because it is part of the Maven coordinates. And Eclipse needs a name for the project. 99.999999% of the time, those would be the same really. In latest Eclipse and M2E, there's even a feature to rename both the project _and_ the artifactId at the same time. Also, you are **not** required to enter a project name. The "Create a Maven project" dialog does not show the Eclipse project name but the Maven name, i.e. `<project><name>` element.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I think you have a misconception. What exactly are you refering to by "Project name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the important value is the artifact name. It will be used as filename for the jar oder war file your projects create.

Maven identifies artifacts with GAV coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version). The groupId usually matches somewhat your package naming.

As an artifactId I would choose something that identifies the origin (projectNameKey-core, projectNameKey-web, ...).

The project name is used simply for printing out the name as human readable text so its usually more verbose. It is shown in the maven output and the site output but has not much more influence to dependencies (unlike the artifactId).

There are also module names (for maven multi-module builds). I usually recommend to use the artifactId as module-name (some plugins and IDEs work better that way).

So choose the  project name freely - no harm done, changeable at any time. Choose the artifactId wisely. It will be used to reference the artifacts you create.